# present a freeform viewcontroller and set its labels

Tags: ios, viewcontroller

I've been recently developing an app that uses a freeform view controller. Everything was fine until I wanted to set the button title label's text considering localization.

I tried to set the text multiple ways but nothing seems to work. At first I was instantiating the view controller from storyboard using its storyboardID like so :

```
    self.dropDown = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"dropDown"];
```

but then I realized that I cant set controller's titles. Or at least I didn't know where to set them. I have them all connected via storyboard as properties. I tried to set the button's title in the viewDidLoad method of the DropDown.m class, nothing. I've also tried to set the title in the controller where I am presenting the dropDown like so:

```
    [self.dropDown.priceAscendingButton.titleLabel setText:NSLocalizedString(@"priceAscending", nil)];
    [self.dropDown.priceDescendingButton.titleLabel setText:NSLocalizedString(@"priceDescending", nil)];
    [self.dropDown.dateAscendingButton.titleLabel setText:NSLocalizedString(@"dateAscending", nil)];
    [self.dropDown.dateDescendingButton.titleLabel setText:NSLocalizedString(@"dateDescending", nil)];
```

but nothing worked ..

Could you please help me ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this

```
[self.dropDown.priceAscendingButton setTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"priceAscending", nil) forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```